# How to copy object and create new object with existing Json object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, json

I am trying to create new object that will have some default values from scope.

I found there is copy function to create new independent object.

`angular.copy(source,destication)`

But its not working for me. I get undefined when I console new object.

```
angular.copy($rootScope.answers,$rootScope.default);
console.log($rootScope.answers);
console.log($rootScope.default);
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/BFGXr7LNAe0KvQipj9JJ?p=preview

In app.js in .run method I trying to use copy function.
Please let me know if I am missing anything.

Comment: `Object.assign({}, source)`

Comment: Refer : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Cloning** is an option. Below is an example:

```
var deepClonedCopy = jQuery.extend(true, {}, originalData);
var clonedData;
clonedData= $.map(deepClonedCopy, function(el) { return el });
```

See this article to get detailed explanation: http://heyjavascript.com/4-creative-ways-to-clone-objects/

**Additional answer added:**

You need to define `$rootScope.default={};` before performing copy.

```
$rootScope.default={};
angular.copy($rootScope.answers,$rootScope.default);
console.log($rootScope.answers);
console.log($rootScope.default);
```

See the updated plnkr : https://plnkr.co/edit/hef6uSHyFRoxs33kRAS8?p=preview

**Alternatively** you can do like this too:

```
$rootScope.default = angular.copy($rootScope.answers);
```

Comment: there are many ways to do it, I am trying to achieve it in angular js. why angular.copy function is not working for me.